# Interpolation of 2D camera with pan and zoom

Tags: animation, math, graphics, interpolation, graphics2d

I'm developing an animation application with 2D virtual camera. The camera viewport can be positioned and scaled in the keyframes and is then interpolated to render the final animation. I'm looking for the best way to interpolate the camera's parameters of x,y position, scale so that objects in the scene transformed by the camera change size at a constant rate and so that all objects travel in a straight line.

The transform matrix for rendering the scene from the point of view of the camera is calculate from the position and scale as follows, where DimX, DimY are the dimensions of the scene image, Pos and Scale are the position and scale of the camera (the variables that I want to interpolate).

```
  LCen := PointF(DimX*0.5, DimY*0.5);
  CamTransformInv := TMatrix.CreateTranslation(-(Pos.X + LCen.X), -(Pos.Y + LCen.Y));
  LScaleInv := 1 / Scale;
  CamTransformInv := CamTransformInv * TMatrix.CreateScaling(LScaleInv, LScaleInv);
  CamTransformInv := CamTransformInv * TMatrix.CreateTranslation(LCen.X, LCen.Y);
```

Here's an animation created by linearly interpolating the scale and position. The black line extends from the center of the viewport in the first position to the center of the viewport in the second position. You can see the effect of it appearing to speed up as it zooms in, which I'd like to avoid. On the plus side, all objects in the scene move in a straight line. I've made the animation loop to make the acceleration effect more obvious.

[image: linear]

So I modified my code to linearly interpolate the Ln of the scale and take Exp of the result. This results in an exponential interpolation with the scale change slowing down as it zooms in which looks good since objects in the scene then grow at a constant rate. This makes sense because objects in the scene get multiplied by scale whereas objects get added by position, so interpolation of scale has to be multiplicative. This is achieved by taking log before interpolating. Position is still linear as before. The problem now is that parts of the image to the sides of the line move in a curve. It doesn't look right (see the top of the tower).

[image: log linear]

It occurred to me that the problem is because I'm interpolating the scale non-linearly and the position linearly. If I made the position decelerate in the same way that the scale is decelerating then it would look correct. However, I can't think how this would be computed as the position and scale are coupled in a complex way. If there's no scale change then the position should change linearly, but the greater the scale change the greater the non-linearality of the position should be.

So is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [answered for me elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/188859/147229). Here is my working code.

```
  CamT.Scale := Exp(LinearInterpolate(Ln(Cam1.Scale), Ln(Cam2.Scale), k));
  if abs(Cam2.Scale - Cam1.Scale) > 0.001 then begin
    r := Cam2.Scale / Cam1.Scale
    w := (Power(r, k) - 1) / (r - 1);
    CamT.Pos.X := LinearInterpolate(Cam1.Pos.X, Cam2.Pos.X, w);
    CamT.Pos.Y := LinearInterpolate(Cam1.Pos.Y, Cam2.Pos.Y, w);
  end else begin
    CamT.Pos.X := LinearInterpolate(Cam1.Pos.X, Cam2.Pos.X, k);
    CamT.Pos.Y := LinearInterpolate(Cam1.Pos.Y, Cam2.Pos.Y, k);
  end;
```

And the resulting zoom.

[image: Corrected zoom]

Comment: Please give a full example

Comment: Sorry, a full example including how I made the animation would take a long time since I can't share my full code. This was mainly a maths question and so I think my answer is sufficient.